# Where is the parameter defined

Tags: f#

This is a simple implimentation of factorial function in F#

```
let rec fact =function
   | 0->1
   | n-> n * fact(n-1);;



   fact 5
```

1-  what is the role of the `rec` word here?

2- fact is the function, but it is never mentioned that it can have a parameter.
So technically it should face with an error, since in the signature
 (`let rec fact` ) there is no parameter defined for it.
So how does it works?

Comment: just as a warning: while this is *recursion 101* it is one of the worst possible implementations for fact (very slow, will blow the stack, ...) - here is a better one: `let fact n = List.fold (*) 1 [1..n]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) `rec` is used to mark function as recursive. Without it you would not be able to call it from within the function implementation. Read more on MSDN: [Recursive Functions: The rec Keyword (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233232(v=vs.100).aspx)

2) `let rec fact = function` is a shortcut for:

```
let rec fact argument =
   match argument with
   | 0 -> 1
   | n -> n * fact (n-1)
```

As you can see, there is a single parameter which is pattern matched with provided conditions.

It's called a **pattern matching function** and is described on MSDN: [Match Expressions (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233242(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I think one of the irritating things here is the `function` keyword, which doesn't correspond at all to what it actually does.